# On Chrome Viewing Certificate Signature Algorithm for SHA224WITHRSA is displaying OID instead of SHA224

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, sha

I am using a self signed X509Certificate with version **V1** and **sha224** as signature algorithm, on a https server and upon accessing the server URL from chrome, the webpage loads successfully. When I try to view the certificate on chrome, I can see that the Signature Algorithm field contains the OID value and not SHA224 (Attached the screenshot of the same). When I export the same certificate to local system and print its contents on the command line using openssl, the signature algorithm shows correctly as SHA224WITHRSA and not the OID. 
I tried using another certificate having **sha256** as signature algorithm on my server and the View certificate on chrome correctly shows the Signature Algorithm field as SHA256RSA as expected and not OID.

Why does chrome show the OID in the Signature Algorithm field of the View Certificate ONLY FOR **sha224**?

[image: View Certificate]

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: object identifier for SHA224 is not registered in Windows OID database, so it shows raw OID value, instead of mapped friendly name.

**Update:**

OID database is hidden and you can register OID mapping using `CryptRegisterOIDInfo` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptregisteroidinfo. There are no other built-in tools to register OID mapping I'm aware of.

Comment: So should we add the mapping explicitly in Windows OID database? If yes, which file in the system should we update (Our systems are Windows 10) or can you help with the command?

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response. Also I stumbled upon similar article which can help others too - https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/how-to-register-custom-object-identifier.aspx

Comment: Even though, I own this article, I'm not responsible for any issues caused by improper code usage. The code was not tested against Windows 10.